# Java's compareTo method - cannot find symbol error

Tags: java

Java noob here trying to implement an AVL tree but I'm getting hung up trying to get the `compareTo()` method to work.  Sorry for the code dump!

```
public class AVLTree<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>>
{

    //Constructor
    AVLTree()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public void SanityCheck()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }

    public void Insert(AnyType x, AVLNode<AnyType> insertAtNode)
    {

        //if starting node is null, it is the root.
        if(insertAtNode == null){
            if(root == null){
                root = new AVLNode(x);
            } else{
                Insert(x, root);
            }
        } else{
            if(compareTo(insertAtNode.element, x) > 0){ //Bias here.  Fix later
                if(insertAtNode.rightChild == null){
                    AVLNode newNode = new AVLNode(x);
                    insertAtNode.rightChild = newNode; //Actual insertion happens here
                } else {
                    Insert(x, insertAtNode.rightChild);
                }
            } else{
                if(insertAtNode.leftChild == null){
                    AVLNode newNode = new AVLNode(x);
                    insertAtNode.leftChild = newNode; //Actual insertion happens here
                } else{
                    Insert(x, insertAtNode.leftChild);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class AVLNode<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>>
    {
    //Constructor
        AVLNode(AnyType theElement)
        {
            element = theElement;
        }

        AnyType element;
        AVLNode<AnyType> leftChild;
        AVLNode<AnyType> rightChild;
    }

    AVLNode root;
}
```

Ignore the algorithm - it's obviously unfinished.  But why do I keep getting the "cannot find symbol: compareTo" when I try to compile?  Thanks

Comment: You should **NEVER** give a Java method a name that starts with a lowercase letter.  Follow the style rules.

Comment: By the way you are potentially making a mistake with your `private class AVLNode<AnyType ...>`. The inner class captures the outer class' generic declaration. Basically you don't need to explicitly declare `AVLNode` as generic and probably shouldn't because its type declaration hides the outer scope's type. `AVLNode` already can access the `AnyType` from `AVLTree`. Either that or declare `AVLNode` as `private static class AVLNode<AnyType ...>`.

Comment: @stephen Uppercase*.

Comment: Arrggghhhh ..... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a method named `compareTo` in the current class.

You probably meant to call the `compareTo` method of `insertAtNode.element`:

```
if (insertAtNode.element.compareTo(x) > 0) {
    ...
}
```

Another thing to note is that by Java convention, method names are camelCase. For example, `SanityCheck` should be `sanityCheck`.

Comment: I'm ashamed of myself. Thanks.

Comment: @BenGorman It's OK to make this type of mistake when you are new. ; )

Comment: @August Isn't your comment about method names being camelCase the opposite of what Stephen C said in the comments above?  Which is correct?

Comment: Pretty sure Stephen C misspoke - [these are the Oracle conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)